# Origin of individual faces don't show up

Tags: transforms, faces, origin

I have a cool model I'm making, but I want to move faces of my model outward along the normals of the faces, so I set the pivot point to individual origins and the transform orientation to normals, but this doesn't work and I can't actually see the individual origins, but when I watch videos on youtube about it they do have the individual origins showing up. Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWStG.jpg (I'm moving the faces in this picture)

Comment: Please use the tools from this site 
to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Yeah I know how to do it, but the file was to big.

Answer (score 1):

To move faces along their individual normals, you need to change the Transform Orientations to "Normal" as well as the pivot point to individual origins. Then use G -> Z to move the faces along their individual normal direction.

[image: Move Normal]

If you wish to add geometry, use "Extrude Along Normals"

[image: Extrude Normals]

And to visualize the normals, the setting is in the Viewport Overlay dropdown:

[image: Overlay]

Comment: Yeah ok thanks, it doesn't do exactly what I wanted, but it's close enough. Thank you